# Match set of keywords taking into account plurals, continuous forms and other variations

Tags: c#, java, full-text-search

What is the approach to be followed to match sets of keywords/phrases where the match can take into account plurals as a match, -ing variations of words as a match and other variations that search engines recognize.

Sets of keywords S1={k1, k2.. kn}; S2={a1,a2.. an}

The goal is to match kis with ais taking into account plurals, -ings etc. as a match. i.e, run could match with running, runs, ran etc..

The part where I seem to think that some reusable component could be used and cannot figure out what, is to get the variations of a keyword possible, or to stem both the keyword sets to the lower order possible.

An implementation detail in C#, Java is preferred.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: If you need full text search and stemming - you can try solr as a ready solution.